# Como se puede crear inputs dinamicamente con un select sin ocupar un boton con js y html?

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera poder crear unos inputs mediante un select, ejemplo un select del 1 al 5 en donde yo selecciono un numero(2) y se debe crear 2 inputs peros sin ocupar un boton

Aqui en el index esta el formulario html en donde selecciono la cantidad de preguntas que tendra una encuesta con un select.

index.html

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
                <h4 class="text-center">Crear Encuesta</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Tipo Encuesta</p>
                    <input type="text" id="tipoencuesta" name="tipoencuesta" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Nombre Encuesta</p>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre-encuesta" name="nombre-encuesta" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Cantidad Preguntas</p>
                        <select id="option" class="form-control" name="">
                            <option value="0">Cantidad Preguntas</option>
                            <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
                            <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
                            <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
                            <option id="4" value="4">4</option>
                            <option id="5" value="5">5</option>


                        </select>

                        <div id="input"></div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="siguiente" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">Siguiente</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui en el archivo javascript realizo la creacion de los inputs dependiendo del valor del select que uno seleccciona.

generador.js

```
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
var select = document.querySelector("#option");
var i ="";
var input = document.querySelector("#input");

select.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
for(i =select.value;i<=select.length;i++){
    createInputs();
}   


});

function createInputs(){
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML=`
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Pregunta ${i}</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    `;
    input.appendChild(element);


}



});
```

Answer (score 2):

He modificado algo tu codigo, a ver si esto es lo que buscas:

```js
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var select = document.querySelector("#option");
    var i = "";
    var input = document.querySelector("#input");

    select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        input.innerHTML = '';
        for (i = 0; i < select.value; i++) {
            createInputs();
        }
    });

    function createInputs() {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = `
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Pregunta ${i + 1}</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    `;
        input.appendChild(element);
    }
});
```

```html
    <form id="form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Crear Encuesta</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body bg-light">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p>Tipo Encuesta</p>
                            <input type="text" id="tipoencuesta" name="tipoencuesta" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p>Nombre Encuesta</p>
                            <input type="text" id="nombre-encuesta" name="nombre-encuesta" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p>Cantidad Preguntas</p>
                                <select id="option" class="form-control" name="">
                                    <option value="0">Cantidad Preguntas</option>
                                    <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
                                    <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
                                    <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
                                    <option id="4" value="4">4</option>
                                    <option id="5" value="5">5</option>
        
        
                                </select>
        
                                <div id="input"></div>
                        </div>
        
                        <button type="submit" id="siguiente" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">Siguiente</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos